# Confusion About Operator Precedence

Tags: javascript, operators, operator-precedence

Im going through the 'Grammer' chapter in [Kyle's You Dont Know Js](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch5.md).

As per [this link at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), `...++` `Postfix increment` has a higher precedence over `=` & even `++...` `Prefix increment`. Yet, in javascript, the following code seems to prove otherwise.

```
var a = 1;
var b = a++; // b = 1; a = 2;
var c = ++a; // c = 3; a = 3;
```

What am I getting wrong? Doesn't the above code show that `=` & `...++` `Postfix increment` have a higher precedence over `=` & `++...`?

Comment: Provided code is more about Post and Pre increment than `precedence`

Comment: post increment/decrement always "returns" the previous value - precedence is irrelevant to the "return" value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of evaluation is (from high precedence to low): postfix operator `a++`, prefix operator `++a`, addition operator `+` (from left-to-right), and the assignment operator `=`, from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

Take a look at the following:

```
var a = 1;
var b = a++ + ++a + a++;
// The order is:
// b = 1 + ++a + a++;
// b = 1 + ++a + 2;
// b = 1 + 4 + 2;
// b = 7; a = 4;
```

The order of evaluation is maintained, just that the postfix operator increments the value of `a` after the last operation has finished, i.e. the assignment operator.

Comment: Thank you, it took me many reviews to fully grasp your example but I feel I am getting it now. Good example & the answer accepted.